# Why are UIViews background color is not updating?

Tags: swift, uiview

Switch statement works but won't reset view background colours etc.

I have a `UIImage` (icon) and a `UIButton` embedded within a `UIView` (of custom type `DropShadowCircleView`) as per image below.

[image: buttons]

When the walking button is tapped a `var navigationOption` is set to either `walking` or `driving` and `setupNavigationSelectionView()` is executed.

**Problem is**: case "**walking**" of the switch works perfectly, but case "**driving**" doesn't reset the `UIView` and icon tint color witcback to their original setting eg; background color etc.. any ideas why?

```
func setupNavigationSelectionView(){

        switch navigationOption {

        case "walking":
            walkingBg.setGradientBackground(colourOne: softGreen, ColourTwo: softBlue)
            walkingBg.layer.cornerRadius = walkingBg.frame.width / 2
            walkingBg.clipsToBounds = true
            walkingIcon.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        case "driving":
            walkingBg.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            walkingBg.layer.cornerRadius = walkingBg.frame.width / 2
            walkingBg.clipsToBounds = true
            walkingIcon.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        default:
            break

        }
}
```

EDIT: this is my `DropShadowCircleView` class

```
class DropShadowCircleView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {

        setupView()
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    func setupView(){
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.50
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 20
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2


    }

}
```

EDIT: This is my `setGradientBackground` function which is within an extension file to `UIView`

```
func setGradientBackground(colourOne: UIColor, ColourTwo: UIColor) {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colourOne.cgColor, ColourTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code for `DropShadowCircleView` to your question.

Comment: @vacawama I've updated my question with the DropShadowCircleView class.

Comment: Where is `setGradientBackground` implemented? What does it do?

Comment: @vacawama I have edited my question again to include setGradientBackground function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove your gradient layer when you reset your icon.

Add this to your `extension UIView`:

```
func removeGradientBackground() {
    guard
        let idx = layer.sublayers?.index(where: { $0 is CAGradientLayer })
        else { return }

    layer.sublayers?.remove(at: idx)
}
```

and call it when you are resetting your icon.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks @vacawama I appreciate your help. A minor thing is that walkingIcon.tintColor to black is not working.

Comment: Define "not working".  What does it do?  What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I have it working now, I had to set the rendering mode of the UIImage view to .alwaysTemplate before I could use tintColor on it.